# Python Azure Databricks create delta table exception: no transaction log present

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am using Azure Databricks and I am trying to create a Delta table.

**Python code:**

```
delta_save_path = "/mnt/ops/test/alerts"
try: 
  sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE ops.test_alerts USING DELTA LOCATION '" + delta_save_path + "'")
except Exception as e:
  print(str(e))
```

**Error message:**

```
You are trying to create an external table `ops`.`test_alerts`
from `/mnt/ops/test/alerts` using Databricks Delta, but there is no transaction log present at
`/mnt/ops/test/alerts/_delta_log`. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing using
format("delta") and that the path is the root of the table.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you're using is when you want to create a table from the existing data. But it looks like that you're creating an empty table, so in this case you need to provide a schema for your table, like this (schema is fictious):

```sql
CREATE TABLE ops.test_alerts (
  id int,
  metric_nam string,
  timestamp timestamp
) USING DELTA 
LOCATION '<some location>'
```

See [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
delta_save_path = "/mnt/ops/test/alerts"

df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "false").load(delta_save_path)

df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("ops.test_alerts")
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. Note: This post was flagged as a low-quality post. – [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31998346)